# Why do we use this static inside stats1 class ? is that a static method so that we can call it directly?

Tags: java

Is that static a method so we can call it directly ?

```
class stats1 {
    static { 
        System.out.println("Super static");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: That is static Block not a method, you can not call it, it will be called when class will get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It is a `static block`. You may not be able to call it specifically as it executes when the class is loaded.

For more details refer this - http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php

Comment: that means static block acts as a constructor ?

Comment: Its not really a constructor. In a class if there is a constructor and a static block, the static block executes first.